# How to break a loop for getting an integer array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, break

How can I break a loop when I define an integer array with a number and I want to finish the loop by pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
I test **`'\n'`** and **`'\r'`** and **`'\0'`** and **`char(13)`** and **`NULL`** but didn't work !
for example ( in this code i try to stop the loop with ascii code of <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && n[i]!=char(13); i++)
    {
        cin >> n[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: consider placing a conditional `break` statement inside your loop.

Comment: Check the result of `cin >> n[i];` to detect an invalid input (ENTER) and call `break`.

Comment: Because you're checking the value of `n[i]` before you've actually read anything into it.

Comment: If by `char(13)` you mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) value for carriage-return, then use the actual proper carriage-return *character* instead: `'\r'`. Please try to avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: Oh and the comment by @Steve is really important. You check the contents of `n` before it has been initialized. An uninitialized array will have *indeterminate* contents, and even reading indeterminate values is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in C++.

Comment: Use std::vector and push_back.. Use a while loop:`int i; while(cin>>i)`

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*: you *read* an element from `n` before writing it: `int n[100] = {};` is a fix for that.

Your specific problem here is that you need to check the error state of `cin` if an `int` is not readable from the stream: use something like `std::cin.fail()`.

Also, don't hardcode character values (presumably that's what `char(13)` is doing?), as then you're not writing portable code. Use `'\r'` &c. instead.

Comment: thank you for answering bro.
but i'm checking that every time that loop is on . 
and the other thing is i'm not allowed to use any function !
also i tried \r is i said .

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code `n[i]!=char(13)` to `n[i-1]!=char(13)`, because when you check the value of what your enter, the variable `i` has been changed to `i++`, so the value of `n[i]` is undefined,and you will always get true.

Comment: it is very nice thing that i learn /. ( thanks )
but the loop still won't stop / !